# Overloaded == is not working for binary tree

Tags: c++

```
bool Tree::operator==(const Tree &that) const {
    return Node::is_equal(this->getRoot(), that.getRoot());
}

bool Tree::operator!=(const Tree &that) const {
    return !Node::is_equal(this->getRoot(), that.getRoot());
}


int main(){
    Tree *t = new Tree();
    const Tree *t2 = new Tree();
    cout << (t == t2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The overloaded == function is not being called and I am not sure why? Instead it is just comparing the addresses in memory.

Comment: you currently compare pointers, do `*t == *t2`

Comment: what is `is_equal` ?

Answer (score 2):

In

```
Tree *t = new Tree();
const Tree *t2 = new Tree();
cout << (t == t2) << endl;
```

you compare pointers to *Tree*, to call your operators you need to compare *Tree*, so :

```
Tree t, t2;

cout << (t == t2) << endl;
```

or using your pointers it is needed to dereference :

```
Tree *t = new Tree();
const Tree *t2 = new Tree();
cout << (*t == *t2) << endl;
```

Comment: I have normally seen `operator==` implemented as a friend function, but I see no reason why it is *required* to do so, rather than as a class member. Wikipedia appears to agree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Comparison_operators/relational_operators

Comment: It is a common practice in C++ community to define operator functions as a friend function, that includes <<. >>, (), +, -, *, /, ^^ functions as well.....

Comment: @YunfeiChen yes, personally I always define them as friend function, and in the first version of that answer I proposed to do that because I didn't know it is also possible to use a class member.